# Beamer titlepage\\line 17 Undefined control sequence

Tags: beamer

I'm so sorry for  the probably stupid question, but somehow I'm stucked. It's my first try to make a presentation in LaTeX. So I will approve every one of your advices (probably a site or something to start with).

Of course I'll delete my insignificant question afterwards, so no worries about that one.

Thank you for your understanding!

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Berlin}
    \usecolortheme{beaver}

    \definecolor{gr}{gray}{0.90}
    \title{3D- Lithography}
    \subtitle{Microfabrication through Two-Photon Photopolymerization}

    \institute[]{\normlsize Material Science Seminar\\
    University of Stuttgart\\[\baselineskip]
    }
    \author{Biri Dimi}
    \date{\today}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame} 
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \AtBeginSection[]
    {
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
    }
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Typo: `\normalsize`, nicht `\normlsize`!

Comment: You have `\institute[]{\normlsize Material...}`. It should be `\institute[]{\normalsize Material...}` (there's an "a" missing in `\normalsize`).

Comment: @JosephWright how to recognize such typo mistake, when the notifier sends me like several lines under it?

Comment: @Biri your code produces the massage `! Undefined control sequence.
\insertinstitute ... {\beamer@andinst }\normlsize 
                                                  Material Science Seminar\\...
l.19     \end{frame}` and the last word of the line immediately after "! Undefined control sequence." is where the problem is. Unfortunately a comment doesn't allow proper code formatting, but the last word in the relevant line is `\normlsize`, so that's where the problem lies.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina well, perhaps it wasn't that difficult than I thought. But as I said I'm new to that and really don't know from where to start. Till now I managed to write some reports, but I really feel ashame so perhaps you could give some advices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you typeset the example, you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\insertinstitute ... {\beamer@andinst }\normlsize 
                                                  Material Science Seminar\\...
l.19     \end{frame}

?
```

Crucially to understand the problem, TeX splits the problematic line at the undefined control sequence, here `\normlsize` (should be `\normalsize`). It's this 'split' in a line that tells you where the problem is: the error actually gets trapped not at the point of input but at the point where `beamer` tries to use the information, which is why we see internal stuff such as `\beamer@andinst`.

Comment: thanks some more literature/sites hints in order to get easier with the program

Comment: @Biri http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11